# Generate faces form single mesh edge?

Tags: mesh

My first post, and no im not suck in edit mode!

I downloaded a model of an oil rig from blend swap created by "B M." as i'm hoping to model one of my own.

Upon opening the blend file i noticed that the beam like support structures pictured below are modeled in a particular way where it looks to be single verts with edges that then somehow generates faces around it.

[image]
[image]

This don't seem to be the work of a modifier. Something seems to be going on under the 'Shape Tab' within 'Data Object' options, as when i tweak the 'Fill values' and the 'Bevel Factor' the geomerty generated around the faces of the single Vert and Edge begins to take shape / deform.

In sum

1. What is going on here?
2. how do i achieve this type of modeling?
3. what other applications could this type of modeling be used for?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: They are 'Curves', look into that.

Comment: @lukeD Thanks Luke, your right. i guess to begin with i didn't know what i was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help! i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three distinct ways to do this.

1. Either use *Bezier Curve* objects. They have the advantage of being simple to edit for tubular structures, can easily bend and make curves, and can have custom sections

[image: Bezier curves]

2. Use a mesh with a *Wireframe* modifier. It is fast to process and is a mesh, so can have a lot more modifiers on top than a bezier curve

[image: Wireframe]

3. Use a skin modifier. It is slower to process and computationally heavy to handle, but will generate cleaner topology and have proper intersections at the joints.

[image: Skin modifier]

Comment: Now it all makes so much sense! Bezier Curves! Thank you so much. I Really appreciate the time you've taken to help me. It means a lot!